# How to fix json decode error in flask test_client().post()?

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to write a test suite for a Flask JSON API, but can't seem to pass `{"form_id": "data"}` into the `json=` parameter of the `app.test_client() post()` method.

`{"form_i": "data"}` works fine, and I've tried setting various encoding options without any luck.

```
with app.test_client() as c:
  test_call = c.post("api/signup/", json={'form_id': 'hi'})
```

Gives the following error message:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 8 column 4 (char 123)
```

Comment: What version of Flask are you using?

Comment: Flask 1.0.2 with Python 3.7.0

Answer (score 0):

recommend this to you

```
import json
with app.test_client() as c:
  test_call = c.post("api/signup/", 
                     data=json.dumps({'form_id': 'hi'}), 
                     content_type='application/json')
```

```
@app.route('api/signup', methods=['post'])
def signup():
    json = request.json
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, turned out to be a different error – was calling a separate JSON file and forgot to remove a trailing comma...